# Does OpenJPA support Where In Select queries?

Tags: sql, db2, openjpa

So I have a query as follows that I am trying to run on DB2 using OpenJPA:

```
 @NamedQuery(name="getStuff", 
            query = "SELECT mtl.final, mtl.entity " +
            "FROM MCT mct, MTL mtl " +
            "WHERE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " +
            "AND mct.cTotPK.Label IN ( SELECT mccp.cCPPK.cPLC " +
            "FROM MCCP mccp WHERE mccp.cCPPK.cLC = '#My String#')")
```

I can get rid of the WHERE IN SELECT statements (bottom two lines) and it will run. So I can't figure out what's wrong with the bottom two lines.

Whenever I run this though I get the DB2 error:
**DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=FOR;AND OR HAVING GROUP INTERSECT ORDER ) FETCH EXCEPT MINUS UNION, DRIVER=3.61.75**

When I looked this error up I found that it is an "illegal use of a keyword" but I really don't know what else I could do. Is there an alternative to the WHERE IN SELECT that I could try out? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the name `mct.cTotPK.Label` `mct` is the table, `cTotPK` is apparently the column, but what is `Label` then? Ditto `mccp.cCPPK.cPLC`.

Comment: @mustaccio - This is presumably JPQL, and `MCCP` is a Java class name, with each element a member variable.  I was initially confused too.  We need more information, like what statement the system is actually trying to run.  [It looks like subqueries are supported](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries).  If there's only one row per relationship, you could change this to a join.